# Connection Authentication between IBM MQ and Weblogic JMS

Tags: ssl, jms, ibm-mq, weblogic-10.x, mq

I have success fully created a JMS bridge between IBM MQ and Weblogic JMS on two different machines and we have enabled both connection as well as message authentication on IBM MQ server but to establish a connection I am providing my Weblogic JMS server's(machine where it is installed) userid/password and hostname.
I do not want to provide the userid/password to IBM MQ. so how can I establish a connection between IBM MQ and the machine where my Weblogic JMS running. Can I implement ssl/TLs digital certificate to authenticate. we have weblogic 11g and IBM MQ v7.5.

please advice

Comment: Yes you can pass certs around with weblogic... do you have more details you would like to add to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, IBM MQ allows you authenticate connections using SSL/TLS.

Comment: can you provide me the necessary steps to perform the authentication.